# Run a query before navigate the link

Tags: c#

I use a WebBrowser  in my app. I want run a query after clicking the hyperlink.this query determine which page is shown. can anybody help me?

Comment: Hyperlink is essentially a URL for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293349/run-a-query-before-navigate-the-link can be that link you can have own url to support it.

Comment: I know this. i use <a> tag in my html source. i want after clicking this link, run the query and then make URL. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a jquery script:

```
<a id="link" href="..."></a>

<script>
    $('.link').onClick(function() {
    });
</script>
```

and in the function you can run an ajax to do the query.

Comment: I use it in winform. writing ajax is possible?

Comment: Do u mean windows application form?

Comment: i suggested this code for a web application. So I should delete it.